# PowerBuilder application call the Delphi DLL

Tags: multithreading, delphi, sockets, dll, powerbuilder

I call a Delphi DLL (multithread sockets dll) file using PB, When the PB application form closed, it's doesn't terminated really, and it's still Stay in the task manager!!! Why? How can I release
the multithread sockets DLL after powerbuilder application terminated?
Thanks in advance for your reply !

Comment: You haven't given near enough information in order for us to help you. How are you "calling" the Delphi DLL from PowerBuilder? Is there a way for PB to inform the DLL that it's exiting so that the DLL can clean up the threads?

Comment: If you look in the task manager, or better yet SysInternals ProcessExplorer, you'll see that your PB app is NOT terminated.  If it was, the DLL could not be in memory.

Comment: @Chris - the OP says PB stays in the Task Manager. DLLs don't show in Task Manager, anyway.

Comment: @Ken, I was merely pointing out that the assertion of "powerbuilder application terminated" hadn't actually happened.

Comment: @Chris - Ah, got it. :) OP's confusion in terminology; one place "application form closed", another "application terminated".

Comment: This is an easy question to answer given enough details, but you need to specify more details.  As it is, we're going to close this question because you didn't bother to give details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dll written in Delphi that is loaded by a powerbuilder application, that does whatever network communications it might be doing would not still be around if the Powerbuilder application had truly terminated.

In windows it is impossible that anything might be keeping your process alive after Powerbuilder terminated it, unless that thing is a thread inside the delphi DLL that is created by the delphi DLL.

I would suggest you monitor the threads that exist in your application, using the delphi debugger. You can start your powerbuilder application from your delphi IDE, by opening your delphi project (that is used to build the DLL) and setting the Project Run Options so that the powerbuilder application that gets run that loads the DLL, is the "executable" in the RUn -> parameters dialog in the Delphi IDE.

Now run the whole thing in debug (green arrow button in the delphi IDE toolbars) and open the Threads panel, and watch the threads starting up in the delphi application. If there aren't any extra threads started by the delphi DLL (say the powerbuilder main thread is the only thread you can see), then the Delphi DLL can't possibly be keeping your application open.

As it is, the most likely thing that's happening is your program is freezing (crashing) because of some basic problem either in powerbuilder or the DLL. Again, solving the problem is probably going to require you to do some debugging, both with powerbuilder and delphi. more information would help people to help you.

Comment: Warren, the original question says it's a multithreaded socket DLL written in Delphi and loaded by PowerBuilder. You've spent five paragraphs basically reiterating what the original question said. :) The issue is most likely that the DLL has threads running that aren't properly being terminated, and PB is waiting for the DLL to unload or signal something before it completely exits; that's why I asked the OP to provide more information. (Chris's comment immediately following mine points out that the OP improperly used "terminated" and "form closed".)

Comment: Thanks for @KenWhite and @Chris's help!I've solved the problem with a compromise method :<br/>`procedure DllMain(Reason:Integer);
  begin
    case Reason of
      DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
      begin
       Client:=TAppClient.Create;
      end;
      DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
      begin
      end;
      DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
      begin
      end;
      DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
      begin
       Client.Free;
       TerminateProcess(GetCurrentProcess,0);// this line
      end;
    end;
  end;`

Comment: But this method just apply to static calls the DLL with PB(or Delphi),otherwise it will terminate the main application~

Comment: The DLL should *not* call `TerminateProcess`! This is just killing PB without giving it a chance to do any cleanup. You need to simply make sure that all your threads are terminated (stopped cleanly), and leave PB alone; it should properly shut down once the threads are stopped and the DLL can be unloaded.

Comment: This question is useless, but it needs one more vote to close it.